# Link on an email to post to a mysql db

Tags: php, html, mysql, email

I need to implement a link at the bottom of an email sent to users, each user should click on it in order to acknowledge he/she received the email -the link and its message will be explicit-, instead of the 1 px image download-from-server method, univ. authorities decided this former approach was a bit nosey, so, the link method was preferred; was this link is supposed to do is to just update the status of email acknowledgement in a mysql db, the link will be dynamically generated so each student would receive a customized link and will be able to click and update his/her -and no one else´s- status once, how do I do this? thank you i.a.

Comment: You start by writing code. We are not here to do your job for you. Once you have some actual code, then we'd be happy to try and help fix it.

Comment: look into get variables and the $_GET method.  I'm sure you'll figure it out

Comment: @MarcB I´m sorry, maybe I asked the wrong way, I never asked for the community to do my job, I just needed some pointers, just like user3479671 did, and maybe some more focused pointers like the other users did, no need to do my job, just some ideas, thanx! :)  (may I get my points back?)

Answer (score 1):

you add the user id and a verification code to your URL like this:
    http://your-site.com/verification.php?id=[user_ID]&code=[unique_verification_code]
where verification.php is the document that receive users' confirmation requests and change their database status and [unique_verification_code] is a unique verification code generated for each user's sign up request

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$emailAddressList = // you create one however you like

foreach ($emailAddressList as &address)
{

$msg = "<a href=\"http://www.yourWebsite/updateStatus.php?arg1=".$address."\">Click HERE to update your status.</a>";
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

mail($address,"YourSubject",$msg,$headers);
}

?>
```

This is really rough code, but can give you a general idea of what to do. It assumes you would have another file called updateStatus.php that updates your database using an email address field to find the correct status.